# Accretion phase duration in a type 1a suernova

Tags: astrophysics, supernova

How long on average does the accretion phase last for a white dwarf in the buildup to supernova/nova, i.e; if it starts at approximately 1 solar mass, how long will it take to reach the 1.4 Chandrasekhar limit?

Comment: How can this be answerable? It depends on the accretion rate for one thing.

Comment: I've flagged this question as `too broad` for the reason @RobJeffries gives.  It's definitely a good question, but an extremely complicated one: especially if you're considering both supernovae and novae (which would have completely different answers) and even different channels for supernova production (i.e. single and double Ia).

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I think in this case an answer could be a reference to some original source, an explanation why is it so complex, and a summarized result.

Comment: Much appreciated for the answers: I was looking for a ball park estimate whether the process takes on the order of thousands/millions of years. I'll look deeper into calculating the duration on some key variables such as the mentioned accretion rate, distance between, dwarfs star mass etc.